# Pandas resample fills values if not present and its effect?

Tags: pandas

I am using tick data and `resample` with `ohlc` to get `1min` data.

I am trying to figure out does the `resample` fill in values if not available i.e. if `10 seconds` are missing in a minute, will `resample` fill data? If yes, then could this `fill` possibly change the `ohlc` values?

Same as above for say a 60 second missing data?

```
   timestamp           close     bid       ask
2 2019-08-20 15:29:10  28021.00  28015.20  28020.0
3 2019-08-20 15:29:20  28021.00  28015.20  28020.0
4 2019-08-20 15:29:58  28020.00  28015.20  28021.0
5 2019-08-20 15:29:59  28020.00  28015.20  28021.0
6 2019-08-20 15:29:59  28015.15  28015.15  28020.0
```

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @jezrael the tick data will be too long imho. Just inquiring about the process more than anything.

Comment: I know, so try only 5 rows sample.

Comment: @jezrael added above. I would really appreciate your input on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Resample**

`resample` will simply take the values that are available within the requested time interval and perform some summary calculation on them. For example:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({"timestamp": ["2019-08-20 15:29:10", "2019-08-20 15:29:20", "2019-08-20 15:29:58", "2019-08-20 15:29:59", "2019-08-20 15:29:59"],
                              "close": [28021.00, 28021.00, 28020.00, 28020.00, 28015.15],
                               "bid": [28015.20, 28015.20, 28015.20, 28015.20, 28015.15],
                                "ask": [28020.0, 28020.0, 28021.0, 28021.0, 28020.0]})
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
df.set_index("timestamp", inplace=True)

                    close        bid        ask
timestamp           
2019-08-20 15:29:10 28021.00    28015.20    28020.0
2019-08-20 15:29:20 28021.00    28015.20    28020.0
2019-08-20 15:29:58 28020.00    28015.20    28021.0
2019-08-20 15:29:59 28020.00    28015.20    28021.0
2019-08-20 15:29:59 28015.15    28015.15    28020.0
```

Then the following will calculate the average `close`, `bid` and `ask` per minute using the 5 data points that are available:

```
df.resample('1T').mean()
                    close       bid         ask
timestamp           
2019-08-20 15:29:00 28019.43    28015.19    28020.4
```

**Interpolate**

If you are missing data for a particular minute and want to interpolate (or "fill-in") data for that minute at a 10-second granularity, then I would suggest the following:

```
resample_index = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='10s')
dummy_frame = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN, index=resample_index, columns=df.columns)
df_resampled = df.combine_first(dummy_frame).interpolate(method='time', limit_direction = 'both', limit = None)
df_resampled

                     close          bid         ask
2019-08-20 15:29:10 28021.000000    28015.20    28020.000000
2019-08-20 15:29:20 28021.000000    28015.20    28020.000000
2019-08-20 15:29:30 28020.736842    28015.20    28020.263158
2019-08-20 15:29:40 28020.473684    28015.20    28020.526316
2019-08-20 15:29:50 28020.210526    28015.20    28020.789474
2019-08-20 15:29:58 28020.000000    28015.20    28021.000000
2019-08-20 15:29:59 28020.000000    28015.20    28021.000000
2019-08-20 15:29:59 28015.150000    28015.15    28020.000000
```

Then perform the same `resample` operation as above.